# Module 'GooglePlaces' not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I installed GooglePlaces, GooglePlacePicker and GoogleMaps as recommended using this Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Myapp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'

  target 'MyappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

In AppDelegate.h

```
@import GooglePlaces;
@import GooglePlacePicker;
@import GoogleMaps;
```

I can see the pods in my Pods directory, but Xcode gives me an error `Module 'GooglePlaces' not found`. I have launched Xcode properly by double clicking the .xcworkspace file.

Interestingly, if I add these pods to a brand new Xcode project, everything works fine. So, there must be some other setting in this specific project which is interfering with the module search path.

Is there a pragmatic way to compare the two projects and isolate the critical difference?

The Framework Search Paths in my project is:

```
Debug -> $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks
Release -> $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks
```

The project where everything works well has a different search path:

```
$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GooglePlacePicker/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GooglePlaces/Frameworks"
```

However, adding this path to my project did not fix the issue.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @LeoChen yes! I uninstalled the google pod, and installed the iOS geolocation instead :-)